# How does var isComplete = false; and the function below work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function checkIfComplete() {

        if( isComplete == false ) {
            isComplete = true;
        } else {
            place = 'second';
        }

    }
```

The full code: https://jsfiddle.net/35xge501/#&togetherjs=R7bkhAnmFG

How does the function and variable work together? For example, how does it know if isComplete = true in the if statement?

Comment: Looks like isComplete is from a higher scope that this function is contained in. It is likely set and manipulated at other places in the outer scope. This method then just checks the value of the variable.

Comment: `isComplete` is set to `false` by default, it's directly stated in the code (`var isComplete = false`).

Comment: Don't post collaboration links.

Answer (score 0):

Hoisting is JavaScript's default behavior of moving declarations to the top.JavaScript only hoists declarations, not initializations.isComplete variable is in global scope so it will be avaiable to function scope.

Comment: What does hoisting have to do with this question?

Comment: Barmar, exactly the question I have